# Nuget Package "Not available in this source"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to get the project started. One of the Nuget packages says "Not available in this source."

It's not a third-party package, but has the name: MyCompanyName.ProjectName.Debug

When I click Restore I get the following error:

> An error occurred while trying to restore packages: Unable to find
> version '1.2.3' of package 'MyCompanyName.ProjectName.Debug'.
>
> C:/Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages: Package
> 'MyCompanyName.ProjectName.Debug.1.2.3' is not found on source
> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages'.
> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package
> 'MyCompanyName.ProjectName.Debug.1.2.3' is not found on source
> 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.

One tip I found was to select "Restore All" from a local NuGet repository, but I'm not able to proceed afterwards.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your company has an internal NuGet feed where the package is published, instead of the public NuGet.org feed. You should ask your coworkers for the feed URL and add it to your configuration with e.g. [nuget sources add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-sources).

Comment: That was it. Turns out they were sharing a physical .nupkg file just for this project. I've added the path to the local disk, and everything works fine now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this error. some of my packages were showing with (!) symbol. Check the same solution with any other system. Respective nuget package files wont be exist in this path - %userprofile%.nuget\packages. We need to manually paste those packages in this path.